# Caching Strategies with Paged/Filtered Data

Tags: java, .net, memcached, theory

I am currently thinking about Caching Strategies and more importantly avoiding any duplication of data inside the cache.  My query is kind of language agnostic but very much programming related.

My question is regarding the efficient caching of paged or filtered data but more than that, distributed caching.  The latter I have decided to go with memcached and more specifically a  .NET port of it.  I have seen another commercial option in the form of NCache, but memcached seems perfectly acceptable to me and apparently is used on facebook, myspace etc...

My query then is a strategy my which you can contain objects in cache and also a reference to them with paged data.  If I have 100 items and I page them, then I could cache the ids of product 1-10 inside the cache and cache each product seperately.  If I where to sort the items descending then items 1-10 would be different products so I would not want to store the actual objects each time the paged data/sorting/filtering changed, but instead stored the ids of the objects so I could then perform a trabsactional lookup in the databse if some of them do not already exist in the cache or are invalid.

My initial idea was this for a cache key.

```
paged_<pageNumber><pageSize><sort><sortDirection>[<filter>]
```

I would then iterate through the cache keys and remove any which start with "paged_"  My question ultimately is if any one knows of any patterns or ideas about straties regarding caching of such patterns of data such as paged data and also making sure that objects are not cached more than once.

memcached is native code and would not have a problem clearing the cache in the way I have stated above, but it is an obvious fact that the more items in the cache the more time it would take.  I am interested if anyone knows of any solution or theory to this type of problem which is currently beig employed.  I am sure there will be .  Thank you for your time

TIA

Andrew

Comment: Are the pages dynamic, is the data on each page constantly changing or is it based on a user query?  Is the application already written and too slow, therefor necessitating the use of a cache? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: The data changes on a prefined set of options, not cached on the users query.  The application is being created.  This is not premature optimization, just planning, as "Failing to plan is planning to fail ;-)"

Comment: Planning is fine, but I would write the application (keeping caching in the back of your mind) and then test it.  If it's not fast enough, add some caching through something like Spring AOP - rather then imbedding caching logic into your applications code.  This would also make the question easier to answer, since we could see some actual code [or use case] and suggest where caching would be most beneficial.

Comment: I like the point you are making, but all it is, is that I see an avenue where I know I would want to add a strategy for caching which could include options for paging whilst maintaining uniqueness in the objects stored

Answer (score 1):

I once tried, what I think, is a similar caching strategy and found it unwieldy.  I eventually ended up just caching the objects that make up the pages and generating the pages for every request.  10 cache hits to construct a page is going to be (hopefully) sub second response time, pretty much instant to the users of your service.

If you must cache entire pages (I think of them as result sets) then perhaps you could run the user request through a hash and use that as your cache key.  It's a hard problem to visualize with a concrete example or code (for me at least).